# Form Confirmation JQuery .submit()

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, submit

I have a form that I need to validate using digest authentication. I'm still working on the authentication, but I have the basic HTML form laid out.

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" class="validate">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="password">Email:</label> 
                <input class="required email" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username@target.com">
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input class="required" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login">

        </form>
```

I also have a external js file called digest_auth.js with the method

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function() {
  alert('click');   
  username = $('#username').value();
  password = $('#password').value();
  realm = tokens['realm'];
  nonce = tokens['nonce'];
  qop = tokens['qop'];
  alert('submitted');
  ha1 = bcrypt(username + ":" + realm + ":" + password);
  ha2 = bcrypt("GET:" + "http://localhost:8090/web/login");
  response = bcrypt(ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nc + ":" + cnonce + ":" + qop + ":" ha2);

  $.ajax(
    type: 'GET', // maybe POST?
    url: url,
    complete: function(xhr, status) {
      if (status == 200) {
        // success. save the nonce and nc in the local storage.
        // whenever you send a request to the server, use the nonce
        // and nc
          alert('Success');
      }
      else {
        // failure, try again
          alert('Failure');
      }
    }
  )
});
```

However, the .submit is not being called. I added the alert() at the beginning but I get nothing. I did link the external using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="digest_auth.js"></script>
```

Comment: is your javascript loaded after the DOM (is the script in the body tag)? If not, put it inside a `$(function() { ... your code here.. });` jquery closuer (onready function)

Comment: How are you creating the "url" for ajax?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your ajax request:

Errors:

1. "+" missing in the concatenation for response
2. ajax attributes should be inside braces

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
      alert('click');   
      username = $('#username').value();
      password = $('#password').value();
      realm = tokens['realm'];
      nonce = tokens['nonce'];
      qop = tokens['qop'];
      alert('submitted');
      ha1 = bcrypt(username + ":" + realm + ":" + password);
      ha2 = bcrypt("GET:" + "http://localhost:8090/web/login");
      response = bcrypt(ha1 + ":" + nonce + ":" + nc + ":" + cnonce + ":" + qop + ":" + ha2);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // maybe POST?
        url: url,
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
          if (status == 200) {
            // success. save the nonce and nc in the local storage.
            // whenever you send a request to the server, use the nonce
            // and nc
              alert('Success');
          }
          else {
            // failure, try again
              alert('Failure');
          }
        }
      })
    });
});
```

Comment: inlining would work, but that couples his script to the HTML unecessarily. He's just selecting the element before it's in the DOM (because the script is likely in his `<head>` and not after `onready`).

Comment: I have updated the <form> attributes, check if that alert is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `$('#loginForm')` is executed after the form element exists in the page.

If that script runs and finds no form than the submit will trigger but won't trigger your function.

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/MxgEf/7/​​​

Comment: Sorry, after the form exists.  If that script runs and finds no form than the submit will trigger but won't trigger your function.

Comment: so do i need one of these in my HTML doc $(document).ready(function() { }); ?

Comment: Does it work here for you? http://jsfiddle.net/MxgEf/7/ If you add more of your code to this example I can take a look when it's broken.

Comment: Yes, that is the most frustrating part. It works just fine in jsfiddle but won't work on my compter!!!